# SQL to Access DB connection issues

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, ssis, database-administration

I have a SSIS package connecting to Access DB via SSIS package. The package runs fine in my local. But in Server it's failing with the error message class not reqistered for the connection manager. I do not have Access DB engine or Microsoft office component installed in the server. Do i need to install any component to acquire connection successfully?

Comment: You really need to provide more details. What is the error message?  What does the code look like? What line of code does the error appear in?

Comment: Make sure you have specified the provider correctly.  32/64 bit is a common snag.  http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/FindPost546426.aspx

Comment: this is the error message: Description: "Class not registered".  End Error  Error: 2016-05-09 02:00:20.24     Code: 0xC020801C     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_CANNOTACQUIRECONNECTIONFROMCONNECTIONMANAGER.

Comment: I tried executing in 32 bit as well.. I think i need to install DB engine and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 in the server.. if any one knows please let me know if i'm correct